# Python: Process hangs with futex(0x2a5fcc0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL in multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, futex

So I have a Queue :

```
q = Queue.Queue()
```

And I'm putting some items in it.

```
items = ["First", "Second"]
for val in items:
    q.put(val)
```

And I'm spawning 15 threads.

```
for i in range(15):
   tname = 't-%s' % i
   t = my_thread(some_func, q, tname)
   t.start()

q.join()
```

The my_thread class looks something below:

```
class my_thread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, some_func, q_, name=''):
       threading.Thread.__init__(self)
       self.func = some_func
       self.process_q = q_
       self.name = name
       self.prefix = name


    def run(self):
       stime = time.time()
       logging.info('%s thread staring at : %s' % (threading.currentThread().getname(), time.ctime(stime)))
       while True:
           if self.process_q.empty():
               break
           queue_item = self.process_q.get()
           self.name = self.prefix + '-' + queue_item
           try:
               #run the function
           except Exception as e:
               logging.error('Caught some error')
           finally:
               self.process_q.task_done()


       endTime = time.time()
       logging.info('%s thread finished at: %s' % (threading.currentThread().getName(), time.ctime(endTime)))
```

If i have a look at the logs, what I see is that two or more threads access the Queue at the same time and the while loop doesn't break when the Queue is empty.

Let's say `t-0` thread has taken the `"first"` item from the queue.
But the `t-2` thread might take the `"second"` item before `t-1` thread can take it thus making the queue empty...but when `t-1` did the `self.process_q.empty()` check, the queue wasn't empty. So `t-1` thread never exits/finishes and is left hanging.

If I do an strace on the process id I get the below:

```
Process 13307 attached
futex(0x2a5fcc0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL
```

How do I solve this???

Comment: may your indentation after the wile loop is wrong?

Comment: Yes let me fix that. This a typo

Comment: with the correct indentation my answer below should work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your threads randomly hanging in the blocking self.process_q.get() function. -> **racecondition**

At the moment, the threads are started, the queue is not empty.
The code part ...

```
...
if self.process_q.empty():
    break
queue_item = self.process_q.get()
...
```

is not synchronized over all threads. So may more than 2 threads (queue size = 2) pass the if condition. Two threads are getting results from the self.process_q.get() function while others are blocking and waiting for results from the queue.

The python programm can not exit until all non-daemon threads are finished. So it hangs forever.

Consider to set the threads in daemon mode:

```
for i in range(15):
    tname = 't-%s' % i
    t = my_thread(some_func, q, tname)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```

from https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon :

> **daemon**
>
> A boolean value indicating whether this thread is a daemon thread
>   (True) or not (False). This must be set before start() is called,
>   otherwise RuntimeError is raised. Its initial value is inherited from
>   the creating thread; the main thread is not a daemon thread and
>   therefore all threads created in the main thread default to daemon =
>   False.
>
> **The entire Python program exits when no alive non-daemon threads are left.**

By setting **daemon-mode** to **true**, the programm exits after the queue is empty (q.join()).

Comment: You're a live saver!! Thank you for the in-depth explanation of what setting the daemon-mode to true does!
Just one small clarification, should the sentence in your answer, "By setting daemon-mode to true, the programm exists after the queue is empty (q.join())."    read as    "By setting daemon-mode to true, the programm EXITS after the queue is empty (q.join())."

Comment: Another clarification, suppose after the t.join() statements I have some other statements to run...say print "end". This "end"will get printed right if I set the daemon-mode has true? Its not like the whole python script will do a sys.exit once the queue is empty, correct?

Comment: correct! the q.join() blocks unti the queue is empty. Then the programm will continue executing. In your example ... exit!

Comment: Love you body <3 !